# Xamarin Android - How to make use of System.Data.Linq?

Tags: .net, linq, xamarin.android, xamarin, system.data

I am using Xamarin Android IDE to develop an android business application. I have installed Xamarin Studio version 4.0.13 build 38 and I am trying to port an old .net code library which was dealing with SQL data logic. This piece of code is making use of `Syste.Data.Linq` package which I think not available directly in mono development.

What do I need to do to make this package available to my code OR if this is not possible then what are the best possible alternatives by which I can get the same functionality provided by `System.Data.Linq` to my android development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need actually System.Data.Linq? The one is needed to work with something like Entity Framework (MS SQL database, for instance). But you don't have those on your Android.

You'd rather work with something like `SQLite` (ORM-way).
But in that case you need just common Linq to objects from `System.Linq` namespace.

(You might also want to consider using [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Sqlite-plugin) framework (including, for easy access to Database (or any other specific functionality)). That framework would allow you to build all the data access logic separatly from your interface and support multiple platforms (iOS and Windows Phone as well)).